# CloudKit integration issue : "Permission Failure" (10/2007); server message = "Invalid bundle ID for container";

Tags: swift, integration, icloud, cloudkit

### code sample

```
let publicDB = CKContainer.init(identifier: "iCloud.com.xxxx.xxxx").publicCloudDatabase
                
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "TestUsers", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
                
publicDB.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { records, error in
    print(error)
    print(records)
}
```

### error message

> <CKError 0x282ae46f0: "Permission Failure" (10/2007);
>
> server message = "Invalid bundle ID for container";
>
> op = XXXXX; uuid = XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXX;
>
> container ID = "iCloud.com.xxxx.xxxx">

Comment: Make sure that the "iCloud.com.xxx etc" matches the setting in Containers in  "Signing & Capabilities" in the Target.

Comment: Hello @johnelemans
Thanks for the answer.
I am sure with the spellings and text formate but have no luck.
I guess the problem is from Apple itself.

Comment: You can try to create a second container and connecting to that. If that fails, I would assume the problem is with Apple.

Comment: Thanks @johnelemans 
I ended up creating 6 containers 
Finally 1 is connected.
You are right the problem is from Apple side.

Comment: @pragetX_iOS : pay attention that container ID are case sensitives

Comment: I have the same problem with a sample app. I was able to get it to work once after copying the app over again and again and by using the default id instead of an identifier. Once the app container syncs, the app works fine. But trying another sample app with the same code (except the container name) did not work. Must be an Apple problem, but it seems to have been around for a long time.  There must be a more robust way to connect to the container??

Comment: Facing the same issue. Some applications and containers work whereas others do not. So frustrating.

Comment: yes, exactly it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error because the `bundle Id for container` belonged to another Apple Developer Team. After creating a new one from my Apple Developer Team, the error was gone